# Sorting 1 column where 1 cell is filtered but I want 2 rows to show per filter

Tags: microsoft-excel

I don't know how to explain this but I have 5 contractors and each contractor has 2 rows of information. The columns are, name, location etc.. then rank at the end. I have ranked them but when I sort click filter and the top row has the different filters on automatically I then go and select Rank 1. I want the rank 1 GC to show up WITH the row beneath his. I don't want to put rank 1 in 2 rows for each contractor because it will look funny to the client.

How do I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an additional column, called something like "Top contractor", which has a formula that checks if the contractor name on the current row is the same as the contractor with Rank 1.

For example:

[image]

Bart is Rank 1. So when we filter, we want to show both rows for Bart (regardless of what the other rank is - maybe it's 2 in your data, it's hard to tell).

Anyway, add a formula like this:

```
=IF([@Name]=XLOOKUP(1,[Rank],[Name]),"Top guy","")
```

The XLOOKUP part returns the name of the person with Rank 1 (Bart). We then compare the current row's name with the result of that XLOOKUP. If they're the same, we show "Top guy" (or whatever you want). If they're not the same, we return an empty string.

[image]

Then filter the data on the "Filter" column:

[image]